Proving that sine series is complete
Let's consider the following family of functions
$$
S = \{\frac{2}{\pi} \sin nx \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}.
$$
Of course for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $s_n \in L^2(0, \pi)$ for $s_n \in S.$
I would like to show that the functions from the set $S$ are orthonormal (that's a very simple calculation) and that the family $S$ is complete which is not so obvious for me. Moreover I would like to show, that elements from $S$ form a Fourier series, i.e.
$$
f(x) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n s_n 
$$
for any (probably) odd function $f$ and were $c_n = \langle f, s_n\rangle$.
How can I show the second and the third part?

I am not sure what you mean by completeness unless it is the property that any function in $L^2(0,\pi)$ can be expressed as such a series (not merely the odd functions), i.e., the fact that the sines of integer multiples of $x$ form a Schauder basis of $L^2(0,\pi).$
A direct proof requires a bit more theory than I care to type here, but a lazy approach is to start from the given fact that sines and cosines including the constant $\cos(0x)$ form an orthogonal (Schauder) basis of $L^2(-\pi,\pi).$ Given any $f\in L^2(0,\pi)$ extend it to a function $g\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ by setting $g(x)=-f(-x)$ on $(-\pi,0)$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ on $(0,\pi).$ Since $g$ is an odd function its Fourier series on $(-\pi,\pi)$ only has odd components, and those provide the series expansion of $f$ on $(0,\pi).$
